# How to align elements in different views with leading edge in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have one screen (design is for iPad, but nevermid) where i have list of users with different states, etc.
That’s all easy, but if you notice on the screenshot below, i also have one “greyish” header which has simple things inside it.
The tricky part is - how can i align it to be as on the screenshot. I would prefer to make the grey header as a separate view, but…how to align it with the rest below?
In UIKit there would be constraint for leading alignment…
Any suggestion or comment will be highly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBovo.png)

I have tried with paddings, but i would really avoid any hard code of widths or whatsoever.

Comment: You'd use a `Grid` or `LazyVGrid`. See an example [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563615/5133585).